# Chart.js bar chart labels do not valign

Tags: html5-canvas, chart.js

I added this line in chart.js

```js
ctx.textBaseLine = "bottom";
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `textBaseline`, not `textBaseLine`.